# How can Rey Pilot the Millenium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi

Rey might know how to pilot, due to her years a junk trader, but one scene from The Force Awakens bothers me. The scene where she flies in the Salt mines on Crait and in the Star Destroyer wreckage on Jakku?. How could she, and anyone else who tried, pilot the Falcon? The ship's cockpit is at the opposite end of the ship, so its a pretty steep learning curve. Han Solo and Chewbacca have piloted the ship for years, But how can a newcomer fly the ship with the skill of someone whos been piloting it for years?

Comment: I'm assuming you missed the part of the film series where it's revealed that she's the most powerful would-be Jedi in the Galaxy

Comment: i didn't know that being a powerful Jedi would automatically make you being able to be the best pilot anyone's ever seen. How good of a pilot was Yoda???

Comment: Something the duplicate answers don't mention is that she actually discusses with Han modifications that Unkar Plutt made to the Falcon, and how they affect the piloting of the ship (the compressor added to the fuel line that puts too much stress on the hyperdrive). She has sufficient knowledge of this in fact that it's not unreasonable to assume she may have flown the Falcon at Plutt's behest.

Comment: @xpert - Yoda was a pretty decent pilot. He had his own customer starfighter; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_fighter